# Can't live edit apache2 webpage

Tags: apache, ubuntu, web, webserver, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've set up a Testserver for my Test website. I use apache2, php and mysql. Everything works fine, except that I have to reload apache every time I make a change to my php file. This is really annoying. I would like to live edit my page, This means that when I hit ctrl + s on my Editor, I can refresh the Browserpage an the changes are there.

Is there a way to make this possible? Im pretty sure that when I was using XAMPP, this worked fine.

I hope you can help me.

- Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
- Editor: Atom
- OS: WSL for
  Windows 10 (Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS)

**EDIT 1**

I just created a stylesheet in the same folder. This seems to work fine.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 lhn2 lhn2 670 Jan 19 10:21 index.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 lhn2 lhn2  32 Jan 19 10:19 stylesheet.css
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, people use other software to deploy a web server like EspressJS (Node.js based web server). The server runs on some port like 8080, then you can use Apache as a proxy to forward your 80 port (HTTP) requests  requests to 8080 port (your Node.js server).

Node.js community has TONS of tools to develop web apps (hot loaders, livereload, etc.)

It might not be the answer you are looking for, but that's how modern web apps are being made.

Also, there are tons of ready to deploy boilerplates like this https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix (PHP Framework laravel with webpack)